# Why does my number reverser function produce an infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Whenever i try print the number reverser function i always get an infinite loop,instead of my expected output 54321. Can someone help find the problem? Thanks.

```py
def order(num):
    x=str(num)
    if x==False:
        return None
    else:
        return order(x[1:])+(x[0])
print (order(12345))
```

Comment: A string will never be ``== False``. Test for ``if not x`` instead.

Comment: Hi bob, hope you're doing well. Have you seen my answer? Please give some feedbacks, to know whether it was useful or not. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you compare the string `x` with the boolean `False`. This is not a correct way to test whether string `x` is an empty string or not.

In addition, if string `x` is empty, then you shouldn't return `None`, but an empty string: reversing an empty string should logically return an empty string.

Here I present two ways to fix your function, which I implemented under the names `reverse0` and `reverse1`. I also present a few other alternatives to achieve the same result using python features, under the names `reverse2` to `reverse6`. Finally I present three other ways to reverse nonnegative integers, under the names `reverse7` to `reverse9`.

```py
def reverse0(num):
  x = str(num)
  if len(x) == 0:
    return ''
  else:
    return reverse0(x[1:]) + x[0]
  
def reverse1(num):
  x = str(num)
  if not x:
    return ''
  else:
    return reverse1(x[1:]) + x[0]

def reverse2(num):
  return str(num)[::-1]

def reverse3(num):
  return ''.join(reversed(str(num)))

def reverse4(num):
  x = str(num)
  return ''.join(x[len(x)-1-i] for i in range(len(x)))

def reverse5(num):
  x = str(num)
  return ''.join(x[-i] for i in range(1, len(x)+1))

def reverse6(num):
  y = ''
  for c in str(num):
    y = c + y
  return y

# reverse7 only works for nonnegative integers
def reverse7(num):
  if num < 10:
    return str(num)
  else:
    return str(num % 10) + reverse7(num // 10)

# reverse8 only works for nonnegative integers
def reverse8(num):
  l = []
  while num > 9:
    l.append(num % 10)
    num = num // 10
  l.append(num)
  return ''.join(str(d) for d in l)

# reverse9 only works for nonnegative integers
# reverse9 returns an int, not an str
def reverse9(num):
  y = 0
  while num > 0:
    y = 10 * y + (num % 10)
    num = num // 10
  return y
```

Relevant documentation:

- [builtin `reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed);
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join);
- [An informal introduction to string slices such as `x[::-1]`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: @pjs I edited to take your comments into account. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to your community.
There are some problems with your code:
**First:**
A string never will be equal to `False`.
for instance:
'0' is not equal to `False`.
'' is not equal to `False`.
**Second:**
You cannot add a `String` to `None`.
This Error will be thrown: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`

---

**Modify your code like this:**

```py
def order(num):
    x=str(num)
    if x=='':
        return ''
    else:
        return order(x[1:])+(x[0])
print (order(12345))
```

**Tip 1:** A string can be equal to '' (empty string).